# Using Apache Beam with Rust

Tags: rust, apache-beam

All our serving code is in Rust. To prevent training serving skew we would like to use the same serving code in our batch processes which use Apache Beam. Any pointers of using Rust in Apache Beam?

Answer (score 1):

As of now, there are only Beam SDKs for [Java](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/java/), [Python](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python/) and [Go](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/go/) (TypeScript is on the way, currently experimental).

I see that there is [a requesting issue on GitHub](https://github.com/apache/beam/issues/21089), which was imported from [BEAM-12658](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-12658). The JIRA ticket had some discussions and effort being put into bringing a Rust SDK, but it doesn't seem to have a lot of recent traction.

I'd suggest commenting and tracking the GitHub issue above, or contributing to the project so we can make it happen.

Comment: Thanks! Done. In the mean time would you recommend Python and Pyo3 ?

Comment: Two independent prototypes for a Rust SDK were developed in the last couple of months, they are being consolidated at https://github.com/nivaldoh/beam/tree/rust_sdk . Feel free to join in there.

Comment: Also, if your Rust code can be exposed as a C/C++ API, another option could be wrapping it in Python.